# How to block Chrome extension popup on Amazon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I find it extremely annoying to see Amazon's "Amazon Assistant" banner when I visit the site. I love the service, I just tire of clicking "No, Thanks" every time I visit the site. I've searched for solutions online but haven't found anything useful.

Is it even possible to prevent Chrome extension popups from happing?

Comment: What extension causes this behavior? Can you simply uninstall it? Unfortunately, this is probably not on topic for Stack Overflow, because it appears to be about the use and configuration of software, not about programming. Maybe it's on topic for Super User, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @apsillers I don't have any extensions that cause this, Amazon automatically does it to Chrome browsers. I wasn't sure if SO was the appropriate place for this question, but I'll ask on SU too and update if I hear anything.

Comment: Oh, so you're not asking about a Chrome extension at all. A Chrome extension is piece of software you install as an add-on to your browser. If you haven't gone to the Chrome web store installed an extension that interacts with Amazon.com, your problem is not caused by an extension. In that case, you're just bothered by the normal behavior of a Web page. It's possible that your question could be on-topic for WebApps.SE -- they have [several questions about Amazon already](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question to SuperUsers and it turns out that this is an Opera-exclusive issue. I see this on both stable and developer versions of the browser, with and without plugins, so it's safe to say that the functionality is built-in.

Unfortunate and annoying.

Comment: [cross posting](http://superuser.com/q/1056031) is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yeah, except when people tell you to "post somewhere else, your question doesn't belong here".

Comment: The absolute correct way is to vote to migrate. However, since this question really IS a better fit to [su] and you posted there, you should delete this one.